# Nginx server config URL rewrite to /backend and /frontend directories

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to convert .htaccess file to a nginx server config.

- There is default client side site which is served from - /frontend/public - this works fine.
- There is admin CMS side site which is served from - /backend/public - this doesn't work
- If I go to **/cms** then I get redirected to **/cms/login** which is correct. Nginx displays 404 error though which is not correct.
- If I remove login requirement and go to **/cms** then it displays the web page as expected, but url changes from **/cms** to **/backend/public**.

I am not sure what I got wrong with the `/cms` and `/backend/public` in the nginx config.

nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /home/anon/web/project;

  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name project.test;

  location ~ ^/cms$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /cms/ redirect;
  }

  location /cms {
    rewrite ^/cms(.*)$ /backend/public/$1 last;
  }

  location /backend/public {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
    }
  }

  location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /frontend/public/$1 break;
    }

    rewrite ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_/\-'"$]*$ /frontend/public/index.php last;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_buffering off;
  }
}
```

.htaccess file I am trying to convert into nginx config:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 301 ^/cms$ /cms/

RewriteRule ^cms(.*)$ backend/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ frontend/public/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_/\-'"$]*$ frontend/public/index.php [L]
```